# Call to undefined method Laravel\Socialite\One\TwitterProvider::stateless()

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-oauth, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I am recieving the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Laravel\Socialite\One\TwitterProvider::stateless()
```

The line throwing this error is:

```
$userData = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
```

The above works fine for Facebook Login.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick look shows that the `TwitterProvider` uses a different `AbstractProvider` than the `FacebookProvider`.

This `AbstractProvider` for the `TwitterProvider` does not implement `stateless()`.

So I suppose what I'm saying is...stateless oAuth is not possible with the TwitterProvider in the Laravel Socialite package out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

TwitterProvider needs **secret** with token you could use this method

> userFromTokenAndSecret

Example

```
$user = Socialite::driver('twitter')->userFromTokenAndSecret($token, $secret);
```

Comment: @ Bdwey @Husam Where do you get $token from, and is that the same as TWITTER_CLIENT_ID in the .env file?

Comment: @kp123 After a successful user login with Twitter in iOS, Android or any other platform, Twitter will respond with a token. Send this token to your backend and use this code to fetch and validate user info

Comment: @Husam thanks but Im confused..aren't we trying to log the user in?

Comment: @Husam for example I have ```$redirectUrl = Socialite::driver($service)->stateless()->user()->redirect();``` I am trying to get the redirect URL in the first place...but apparently stateless() does not work, so I'm trying to figure out a way to make this work

Comment: @kp123 We use ‘stateless’ only if the case is to develop an API to validate a successful user login request. If you want to make login for web I suggest you use without stateless.

Comment: @Husam yes...but how? :)

Answer (score 0):

In your loginController, in handleProviderCallback function replace:

```
$userSocial = Socialite::driver($social)->stateless()->user();
```

with:

```
$userSocial = Socialite::driver($social)->user();
```

using:

```
"laravel/socialite": "^3.0"
```

in your composer.json require section.

Comment: Will not work. Since one is stateless and one is stateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get user info from Twitter using `stateless` as Twitter doesn't support `OAuth 2.0` as of I'm writing this. [Link to twitter dev forum](https://twittercommunity.com/t/getting-started-with-oauth-2-0/2338)
However, I have a found a workaround for login using the API.

However, one way to do this would be to redirect using this

```
return Socialite::driver('twitter')->redirect();
```

In your callback, get the returned info using this

```
Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
```

Get the token and other info as you wish from here, then, do your thing and store the credentials in the database and get new database row id and encrypt that value and redirect to your login page with that encrypted value. From your login page, do some operations and check if id like that is present, if yes, then try to log in. Now in `loginController`, do something like this

```
            $authId = $request->get('authId');
            $authId = decrypt($authId);
            $social = SocialAuth::find($authId);
            $user = User::find($social->user_id);
```

and then attempt to login that user using id. Redirect to the log in url with more parameters for more security. 
I hope you get the concept.